# how to print large pictures with Android and USB bulk transfer

Tags: android, usb, zpl

When I transfer the bytes greater than 16384 bytes when the data will be lost,
I have tried libusb, but libusb I did not find the right development documentation for reference, I wonder if there is no better way to solve this problem?
Here is the code that I print through the bulktransfer, when the transmitted data is less than 16384, it is working！

```
//convert pic to ZPL
public class ZPLConveter {
    private int blackLimit  = 380;
    private int total = -1;
    private int widthBytes = -1;
    private boolean compressHex = false;

    private static Map<Integer, String> mapCode = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    {
        mapCode.put(1, "G");
        mapCode.put(2, "H");
        mapCode.put(3, "I");
        mapCode.put(4, "J");
        mapCode.put(5, "K");
        mapCode.put(6, "L");
        mapCode.put(7, "M");
        mapCode.put(8, "N");
        mapCode.put(9, "O");
        mapCode.put(10, "P");
        mapCode.put(11, "Q");
        mapCode.put(12, "R");
        mapCode.put(13, "S");
        mapCode.put(14, "T");
        mapCode.put(15, "U");
        mapCode.put(16, "V");
        mapCode.put(17, "W");
        mapCode.put(18, "X");
        mapCode.put(19, "Y");
        mapCode.put(20, "g");
        mapCode.put(40, "h");
        mapCode.put(60, "i");
        mapCode.put(80, "j");
        mapCode.put(100, "k");
        mapCode.put(120, "l");
        mapCode.put(140, "m");
        mapCode.put(160, "n");
        mapCode.put(180, "o");
        mapCode.put(200, "p");
        mapCode.put(220, "q");
        mapCode.put(240, "r");
        mapCode.put(260, "s");
        mapCode.put(280, "t");
        mapCode.put(300, "u");
        mapCode.put(320, "v");
        mapCode.put(340, "w");
        mapCode.put(360, "x");
        mapCode.put(380, "y");
        mapCode.put(400, "z");
    }
    public String convertFromImg(Bitmap bitmap) {
        String cuerpo = createBody(bitmap);
        if(compressHex) {
            cuerpo = encodeHexAscii(cuerpo);
        }
        return headDoc() + cuerpo + footDoc();
    }

    private String createBody(Bitmap originalImg) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int width = originalImg.getWidth();
        int height = originalImg.getHeight();
        int rgb,red,green,blue,index = 0;
        char binaryChar[] = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',};
        widthBytes = width / 8;
        if(width % 8 > 0) {
            widthBytes = (((int)width / 8) + 1);
        }else {
            widthBytes = width / 8;
        }
        total = widthBytes * height;
        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
                rgb = originalImg.getPixel(w,h);
                red = Color.red(rgb);
                green =Color.green(rgb);
                blue = Color.blue(rgb);
                char auxChar = '1';
                int totalColor = red + green + blue;
                if(totalColor > blackLimit) {
                    auxChar = '0';
                }
                binaryChar[index] = auxChar;
                index++;
                if(index == 8 || w == (width - 1)) {
                    sb.append(fourByteBinary(new String(binaryChar)));
                    binaryChar = new char[]{'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};
                    index = 0;
                }
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String fourByteBinary(String binary){
        int decimal = Integer.parseInt(binary,2);
        if(decimal > 15) {
            return Integer.toString(decimal,16).toUpperCase();
        }else {
            return "0" + Integer.toString(decimal,16).toUpperCase();
        }
    }

    private String encodeHexAscii(String code) {
        int maxLine = widthBytes * 2;
        StringBuffer sbCode = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer sbLine = new StringBuffer();
        String perviousLine = "";
        int counter = 1;
        char aux = code.charAt(0);
        boolean firstChar = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++) {
            if(firstChar) {
                aux = code.charAt(i);
                firstChar = false;
                continue;
            }
            if(code.charAt(i) == '\n') {
                if(counter >= maxLine && aux == '0') {
                    sbLine.append(",");
                }else if(counter >= maxLine && aux == 'F'){
                    sbLine.append("!");
                }else if (counter>20){
                    int multi20 = (counter/20)*20;
                    int resto20 = (counter%20);
                    sbLine.append(mapCode.get(multi20));
                    if(resto20!=0){
                        sbLine.append(mapCode.get(resto20) + aux);
                    } else {
                        sbLine.append(aux);
                    }
                } else {
                    sbLine.append(mapCode.get(counter) + aux);
                    if(mapCode.get(counter)==null){
                    }
                }
                counter = 1;
                firstChar = true;
                if(sbLine.toString().equals(perviousLine)){
                    sbCode.append(":");
                } else {
                    sbCode.append(sbLine.toString());
                }
                perviousLine = sbLine.toString();
                sbLine.setLength(0);
            }
            if(aux == code.charAt(i)) {
                counter++;
            }else {
                if(counter > 20) {
                    int multi20 = (counter/20)*20;
                    int resto20 = (counter%20);
                    sbLine.append(mapCode.get(multi20));
                    if(resto20!=0){
                        sbLine.append(mapCode.get(resto20) + aux);
                    } else {
                        sbLine.append(aux);
                    }
                }else {
                    sbLine.append(mapCode.get(counter) + aux);
                }
                counter = 1;
                aux = code.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        return sbCode.toString();
    }

    private String headDoc(){
        String str = "^XA " +
                "^FO0,0^GFA,"+ total + ","+ total + "," + widthBytes +", ";
        return str;
    }
    private String footDoc(){
        String str = "^FS"+
                "^XZ";
        return str;
    }
    public void setCompressHex(boolean compressHex) {
        this.compressHex = compressHex;
    }
    public void setBlacknessLimitPercentage(int percentage){
        blackLimit = (percentage * 768 / 100);
    }
}
```

And this is the code that I use for transferring the image

```
//Transferring data using bulktransfer

    private void printTask(final UsbDeviceConnection conn) {
        try {
            convertPDFToImg();
            ZPLConveter zp = new ZPLConveter();
            zp.setCompressHex(false);
            zp.setBlacknessLimitPercentage(50);
            command = zp.convertFromImg(bit);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bytes = command.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
       conn.bulkTransfer(pointBulkOut, bytes, bytes.length, 500);
}
```

Comment: Hi, you forgot to add the code excerpt that works for small images.